# Need help modifying Apache RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hired someone to write some RewriteRules for my .htaccess file that would accomplish several things, including defaulting capital letters in URLs to lower case and defaulting underscores and spaces to dashes. So the URL MySite/World/Isle of_Man should default to mysite/world/isle-of-man

They weren't able to do it, but they were partially successful. I wound up modifying the httpd.conf file to handle the lower case stuff. I then added the rules they wrote for defaulting underscores to dashes.

So my RewriteRules now look like this...

```
RewriteRule (.*?[A-Z]+.*) /${tolower:$1} [R]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

And they work pretty well. The URL MySite/World/Isle_of_Man now defaults to mysite/world/isle-of-man

However, it doesn't fix URLs with spaces - just underscores. Also, someone told me the second and/or third line is sloppy; it replaces two underscores instead of one. I'm not sure exactly what that means. If a URL has multiple underscores or spaces, then I need all of them to be replaced with dashes.

Anyway, I wondered if anyone could show me how to modify these rules so they replace spaces with dashes. And if you see anything wrong with the underscore rule, could you advise me how to improve it?

P.S. There are websites that let you type in regular expressions and see how it interacts with various strings. Are you aware of anything similar for testing RewriteRules? When I'm experimenting with my .htaccess files, I also wind up with code that crashes my computer. When I reload a web page, it loads and loads and loads, until all my software freezes up.

Comment: I'm not familiar with htaccess so I could be wrong on this, but are you sure you even need to use capturing groups for the text you want to keep?  Why not just replace `[_ ]+` with `-`?

Comment: @ CAustin - Regular expressions are Greek to me. I hired someone to wrote this code for me. When he accepted, I assumed he knew how to work with Apache, but it took him several days to create some code that didn't even completely work.

Comment: Ah, that's a bummer.  Either way, the simple replacement I mentioned should do the trick, whether you do it before or after the `toupper` operation.  Instead of trying to match the entire string and replace with the parts you want to keep (which is what you're doing with `$1` and `$2`), just try matching the stuff you don't want and replace it with the stuff that specifically takes its place.

Comment: OK, how would you write replace [_ ]+ with -?...what would the whole RewriteRule(s) look like?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not familiar with htaccess, but judging from what you already have, it would probably just be `RewriteRule [_ ]+ - [N]`

Comment: Well, I tried this - RewriteRule [_ ]+ - [N]
RewriteRule [_ ]+ - [L,R=301]
...but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead for changing spaces and underscores to dashes:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?:\ |_)(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,E=DASH:Y]

RewriteCond %{ENV:DASH} Y
RewriteRule ^([^\ _]+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

So the first rule matches anything with a space or underscore, and rewrites it with a dash. Additionally, it sets an environment variable to let the rest of the rules know that it rewrote the URL to add a dash. This first rule will loop until there are no more dashes.

The second rule only gets applied if the "DASH" environment variable was set, meaning that there was a space or underscore that was rewritten earlier. If there are no more spaces or underscores, then redirect the browser to the new URL (which has them all replaced with dashes).

This is a much cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks, but when I paste in those three lines of code and refresh the page, I get an Internal Server Error. If I manually change the underscores to dashes, I still get the error. However, I see what you're trying to do, and it does look a lot better. And I could be doing something wrong somewhere or other; Apache is endlessly confusing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This aught to work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?[A-Z].*) /${tolower:$1} [R]
RewriteRule ^([^_\ ]*)[_\ ](.*?[_\ ].*) $1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([^_\ ]*)[_\ ]([^_\ ]*) /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

- Adding a `\` before a space keeps it part of the regex for a RewriteRule.
- A bit of regex cleanup for readability.

To explain these regexes:

The first says to convert any path with an upper case letter to all lower case, then send a redirect to the user's browser telling it to retry with the new path.

The second says to find paths with at least two spaces and/or underscores and replace the first one, then restart matching from the beginning (thus rematching on each subsequent underscore or space until only one remains).

The final rule matches against any single space or underscore, converts it to a dash, and sends the new (changed) path the the user's browser with a response code 301 "Moved Permanently" which will sometimes update links and shortcuts automatically.

In greater detail:

- `^` at the beginning of each line means to match from the beginning of each address, rather than just anywhere.
- Each pair of `()` is a group that gets dumped to `$1`, `$2`, etc. in the same order they appear.
- Each `.*` says to match as much of any type of text as it can.
- Each `.*?` says to match the smallest amount of text it can to still complete the whole pattern.
- `[^_\ ]*` matches a stretch of non-underscore and non-space characters.
- `[_\ ]` matches a single space *or* underscore.
- `[A-Z]` matches a single upper-case character, which is enough to know that the address needs to be converted to lower case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That helps me understand how these things work. Unfortunately, these RewriteRules aren't working for me; when I visit mysite/world/New_York (or New-York or new_york), it defaults to the site's home page.